# Is it possible to have a value in alert coming from link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just created a HTML file and that file has a link that goes to the server and retrieves the value that is a number.

I am just wondering that can we have that value that is generated by link in that alert box.

**To be clear I dont want link in alert box but I want to display the value that is returned from the server**

See here my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("I am an alert box!");
        }
    </script>
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/TemperatureReading/"> test </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here alert box is saying-

**I am an alert box!**

Now, what I want is can I have value showing in alert box which is the value from the server( the value which is in the link).

This can be very easy but I am not able to get it. Can anyone help me on this issue. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
I have also tried ajax GET request--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>AJAX</h2>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
        function loadDoc() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/TemperatureReading/", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But where to have alert??

Comment: what is the link value? are your referring the href or the test?

Comment: you need which value to be alerted?

Comment: @user2181397 it is numeric...the test is href

Comment: @AnoopJoshi the value which is in link test I want it in Alert box

Comment: where are you seeing value in link test. Please write the value

Comment: I think he going inside that link and he is finding a number and he want to display that number inside his alertbox!i dont think its possible without ajax or retrieving value from json.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mxtvnd6a/) check event handler

Comment: @guradio it will have the link in alert box...I want value that link has in laert box

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha you are confusing with your question and comments. What do you want in alert??  do you want the alert to display **`http://localhost:8080/TemperatureReading/`** as it is in the `href` of the anchor tag **OR** do you want to **display the value that is returned from the server** when it hits the link ?

Comment: @Reddy I want display the value that is returned from the server

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha you need to use Ajax then..

Comment: @Reddy I used it also...I have edited question please see

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha check my answer...

Comment: @Reddy ...I commented in your answer

Comment: @Jamiec I edited the question please see and remove duplicate tag

Comment: What do you get if you type `http://localhost:8080/TemperatureReading/` into your browser? Why in the second example did you change that to `localhost://TempratureReading/JavaResources/src/ReadingController` (which is a almost certainly invalid URL)?

Comment: @Jamiec I will get a random number generated by server...sorry about edit I changed the file path  in that

Comment: Ok, so in your second example, did you see that random number in `<p id="demo">` element?

Comment: @Jamiec In hurry I just not look at that... again sorry

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha huh? That didnt answer my question!

Comment: @Jamiec yes man I see that...it is previous code when I am not able to achieve this thing...Now, when I achieved it I wanted to do this alert thing...

Comment: So the second bit of code works, and you know how to show an `alert` but you cannot join the dots to get an alert instead of writing to `<p id="demo">`? That is incredible! I think you're just after someone to hold your hand!

Comment: @Jamiec sorry man but its not like that....I am just under a gun I have been working on this for couple of days...I think I am eager to get answer without thinking what I am doing...sorry

Comment: @Jamiec please see this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310160/so-chat-no-upload-button/310161#310161....that is why I am not able to see the button...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get href value of test and alert it on clicking button , try this:

```
function myFunction() {
   var href = $("a").attr("href");
  alert(href);
}
```

Comment: Do you want anchor tag text (which id "test" here) OR href of anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you want to display the value returned from the server this is what I suggest you.

- Add the Jquery reference to your page. (I have added from CDN below)
- Use Jquery to do a Ajax call to the link in your anchor tag.
- On this Ajax success method display this returned value in a alert

Sample code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {    
 $.get($('#ajaxedAnchor').attr('href'),function(data){  // shot form of ajax get syntax
    alert(data);                                        // alert the returned data from server
 });     
}

</script>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/TemperatureReading/" id="ajaxedAnchor"> test </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not coming again...but again if I click on link value is showing

Comment: if you click on the link what is showing?? Can you give more details?

Comment: If I click on link it just give me number thats it...and I want that number in alert box

Comment: what is your server side language?

Comment: The number is coming from random generator function and this function is written in JAVA

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha I dont see any error in my code... can you do one help.. copy the contents of the `myFunction()` and paste it in your browser console and execute it... let me know what happens

Comment: Object { readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: .ajax/x.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/x.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/x.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/x.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/x.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/x.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 8 more… }
GET
XHR
http://localhost:8080/TemperatureReading/

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha I asked you to execute the content which I have provide in my answer. :)  that is this code `$.get($('#ajaxedAnchor').attr('href'),function(data){
    alert(data);
 });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112133/discussion-between-shubham-vashishtha-and-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text()` method to get the text of an element, which can be used inside the alert.

```
function myFunction() {
  alert($("a").text());
}
```

Seems like you haven't referred jquery in your code.

Comment: you want me to add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script> this right?

Comment: Sorry but it is giving test inside alert box I want to display the value that is returned from the server

Answer (score -1):

Make POST or GET request to http://localhost:8080/TemperatureReading/
and return variable alert in your page

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score -2):

The following code requires jQuery:

```
function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type：“GET”,
        url:"server address",
        success:function(data){//data is server print 
            alert(data)
        }
    })    
}
```

Comment: I tried this and replaced myFunction with your myFunction but now alert box is not working